# Using malloc for binary search trees

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree

I'm currently learning about dynamic structures in C, but I started to struggle when it got to linked lists, binary search trees, and `malloc`.

First, I am pretty sure `malloc` is used when extra memory needs to be accommodated for fixed-sized elements such as arrays, and `free` for when the extra allocated memory is not used or not required anymore.

**Question**: Why is `malloc` being used for tree_t?

```
tree_t *make_empty_tree(int func(void*,void*))
{
    tree_t *tree;
    tree = malloc(sizeof(*tree));
    assert(tree!=NULL);
    /* initialize tree to empty */
    tree->root = NULL;
    /* and save the supplied function pointer */
    tree->cmp = func;        
    return tree;
}
```

Im pretty sure that variables and pointers declared within functions get destroyed/reset between calls, but any data associated with such variables can be saved by returning it to the calling function.

In the end isn't pointer: `tree` given sufficient (temporary) memory simply upon declaration? Like why can't you just declare `tree`, skip `malloc`, and assign the `tree_t` structure components?

I'm not sure why memory is being allocated, and why `free` is not being used at the end.

Comment: Well, for one, *"Returns a pointer to the tree node storing object "key", if it exists"* is a lie. That's not what that function does. It returns the `void*` in a tree node that matches the specified key. if there is no match, NULL is returned. The actual tree node(s) only enter the picture in the `recursive_search_tree` function, and even then only to find the proper data matching the given key (if it exists). If that function did as the comment states, `return root->data` would be `return root;` and the declared return type of the function would *probably* be `note_t*` , not `void*`.

Comment: When you do: `tree_t *tree;` you declare a variable, i.e. a `tree_t` pointer variable. It can only hold the pointer value (aka a memory address). It can **not** hold a `tree_t` - it can **only** point to some other memory (where a `tree_t` is stored). The `malloc` call reserves this "other memory". So: No - you can't just "skip the malloc"

Comment: `tree` is an uninitialized *pointer* to a `tree_t`. `malloc` allocates the required memory for a `tree_t` struct, using the `sizeof` operator, on the *heap*. The `tree_t` struct is *not* a local variable on the *stack*. It's fields are set through the use of the pointer  `->` operator, and the pointer returned.

Comment: BTW - it's best to restrict yourself to a single question. The first one is fine, and what you've written lets others know what your misunderstanding might be. The following questions are *not* well-posed. 'Explain this code' isn't helpful. When the pointers begin to make sense to you, you'll probably begin to understand the rest.